# Do we have $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Proj}S}(\operatorname{Proj}S)=S_0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a graded ring, do we have $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Proj}S}(\operatorname{Proj}S)=S_0$?

If $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$, then $p^{\operatorname{Re}(s)}>2$ for any prime $p$, $p^{\operatorname{Re}(s)}-1>\frac{1}{2}p^{\operatorname{Re}(s)}$,

\begin{eqnarray}
\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}&=&\prod\limits_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\\
&=&\prod\limits_p\frac{p^s}{p^s-1}\\
&=&\prod\limits_p(1+\frac{1}{p^s-1})
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_p|\frac{1}{p^s-1}| &=&
\sum\limits_p\frac{1}{|p^s-1|}\\
&\le &  \sum\limits_p\frac{1}{|p^s|-1}\\
&=&\sum\limits_p\frac{1}{p^{\operatorname{Re}(s)}-1}\\
&<& \sum\limits_p\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}p^{\operatorname{Re}(s)}}\\
&<&2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{\operatorname{Re}(s)}}\\
&=&2\zeta(\operatorname{Re}(s))\\
&<&\infty
\end{eqnarray}

$\forall s$ with $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$, for any prime $p$, $\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\neq 0$, so $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}&=&\prod\limits_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\neq 0$,

that is, $\zeta(s)$ does not vanish when $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be true if $S$ is a polynomial ring. This follows from Hartshorne Prop II.5.13.

It also states that if $S$ is a graded ring that is *not* a polynomial ring, then this is not true. Exercise 5.14 provides a counterexample.